# Vectorizing access to a slice of a three-dimensional matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, slice

I have a three-dimensional matrix of these sizes, approximately

```
A = rand(20, 1000, 20);
```

where the first and third dimensions are always the same length. I want to zero the elements in a main diagonal slice. This does what I mean

```
for ii = 1:size(A, 1)
    A(ii, :, ii) = 0;
end
```

Is there a vectorized or otherwise faster way to do this? This code runs about 100,000 times, with these approximate sizes, but not the exact same sizes each time.

Comment: Does it run 100k times for the same matrix dimensions?

Comment: Not exactly. It runs ~100 times on each matrix, and there are ~1000 such matrices with slightly different sizes. I would have used a single logical-indexing matrix if it they were always the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to build a linear index of the elements to be zeroed:

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (0:size(A,2)-1).'*size(A,1), 1:size(A,1)*size(A,2)+1:numel(A) );
A(ind) = 0;
```

Comment: This gives better times than Daniel's suggestions, but is still slower than the for-loop method by a factor of >2. Interestingly, this remains the case even if the size of all `A` matrices is constant, and `bsxfun` is only called once. Executing `A(ind) = 0;` 100,000 times is still slower than executing the for-loop 100,000 times. I would guess this is due to faster memory access with `A(ii, :, ii)` compared to accessing "random" indices with `A(ind)`. If this is true, this is a case _against_ vectorizing this code.

Comment: But since I did ask for a vectorized solution, I will accept this answer as the best vectorized solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use logical indexing for multible tailing dimensions while using subscript indexing for all previous dimensions individually. This way you can easily do the operation on an 1000 20 20 matrix. To apply this to your matrix, permute is required which might be slow:

```
n=size(A,3)
A=permute(A,[2,1,3]);
A(:,diag(true(n,1)))=0;
A=permute(A,[2,1,3]);
```

If it would be possible to permanently swap the dimensions of A in your code and avoid the permute, this would lead to the fastest solution.

Alternatively you can use repmat to expand the index to the dimensions of A

```
ix=repmat(reshape(diag(true(n,1)),n,1,n),[1,size(A,2),1])
A(ix)=0
```

For matrices of the same size you could keep ix. Not having access to MATLAB right now, I don't know which solution is faster.

Comment: I tested these methods now. They are _much_ slower. I guess this is one of those places where vectorization is not superior.